# Linking Functional Block (FB) from development project to Testing Project -TwinCAT 3 - Beckhoff

Tags: unit-testing, twincat

I have created a **testing project** to run unit tests using [TCunit framework](https://tcunit.org/) and wanted to link files from **development project** worked by another colleague.
But there is only Add option when i right click on POU folder in solution explorer of TwinCAT.
When i did so, a copy of a file is made in testing project POU folder. Now I have two copies of same file i.e. in POU folder in testing project and POU folder in development project.
The problem i want to avoid is , if there are changes in the development project files i need to update POU folder in the testing project also manually.
Is there any solution to avoid the duplication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried this, but maybe you can try to make a [hard symbolic link](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/) to the folder content you want in your test project. And then import the content from the symbolically linked folder into your test project.

**Edit 18 April 2020**

I made a small [batch script](https://gist.github.com/Roald87/c68ea920607ec8f32d977d32f3f82712) to facilitate the hardlinking.

Comment: @KumaraswamyGaviyappa No problem. How did you add the folders to your unit test project? It doesn't automatically recognize the folders when they are in the project directory right?

Comment: I have created soft link to the files in POU folder in Development folder to Test Folder. Files need to be explicitly added to the project, it doesn't automatically recognize the folders or files.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a library from your development project and reference it in yout Unit Testing project.

By right-clicking on the development project you can select "Save as Library". Once the library is generated you can install the library using the library manager and install the file.

Finally in your unit test project you can add this library by right clicking on the References and choosing the library you just installed.

Unfortunately this still requries to manually update your libray when there are changes but is a somewhat cleaner solution.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion. I think, here i need to create the library every time if there are changes in the Development project. why the referencing is not provided in twinCAT? I feel it important feature and also present in other language and IDE’s .